# Postgres+Hibernate: Mapping UUID to BYTEA fails after upgrading to Hibernate 5.0

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

How to store java UUID as byte array in Postgres using Hibernate 5.0?
Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
public class Child {
  ...
  @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
  private UUID parentId;
  ...
}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE childs (
    ...
    parent_id BYTEA,
    ...
);
```

Everything used to work just fine with Hibernate 4.3. After upgrading to Hibernate 5.0 I'm getting the following error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "parent_id" is of type bytea but expression is of type uuid
```

I checked the source code of `PostgresUUIDType` and found that in the new version of Hibernate the following is added:

```
@Override
protected boolean registerUnderJavaType() {
    // register this type under UUID when it is added to the basic type registry
    return true;
}
```

I tried to change the type of field in the model to `@Type(type = "uuid-binary")`, but still got the same error. (changing the type of column to `UUID` is not an option.)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found to fix this is to add the following to `package-info.java` in the `domain` package (or wherever it's required):

```
@TypeDef(name = "pg-uuid-binary", defaultForType = UUID.class, typeClass = UUIDBinaryType.class)
```

And annotate the domain's field with `ph-uuid-binary` with `@Type(type = "pg-uuid-binary")`.

To me it seems exactly the same as `uuid-binary` definition, but somehow it does not work.